# Two tags for the United States

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Economics SE has tags [usa](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [united-states](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). I propose that they be merged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set [usa](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [united-states](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)  to be tag synonyms. This should solve your problem because if someone uses synonym question will be automatically re-tagged with master tag. We could also merge them but I worry that users will keep creating usa/united states tag because if you just start typing the tag after typing u this tag wont pop up in suggestions  as it is not as frequently used, and thus I am guessing people might keep creating either usa tag or united-states tag (depending on which one will be gotten rid of) recreating this issue.